# Invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p \ge 3$ be a prime and let us consider $U(p^n)$, namely the set of all invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that $1+p \in U(p^n)$? If so, which is its order in $U(p^n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$[k]_{p^n} \in U(p^n) \iff (k,p^n) = 1$$

where $[k]_{p_n}$ is an element of the quotient group with representant $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $MCD(p+1,p^n)=1$, so I have to continue. What about its order? Surely $o(1+p)| p^{n-1}(p-1)$.

Comment: The question says 'if so'. Do you have to continue? You should also show some effort yourself.

Comment: By Euler's Theorem, $(1+p)^{\phi(27)} \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$, right?

Comment: @Math_QED:  I'm confused by your Comment, "Do you have to continue?"  Clearly any common divisor of $1+p$ and $p^n$ would have to be a power of the prime $p$, so... yes.  The OP's problem requires a solution to the second part.

Comment: I didn't actually make the question. The hint was how I would approach the problem. I hoped the OP would show his work so I could see whether he was correct.

Answer (score -1):

The order of $U(p^n)$, $n\geq 1$, is given by Euler's totient function $\phi$ with $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$.

Comment: It seems the Question is about whether $1+p \in U(p^n)$, and if so, what its order is (as an element of the multiplicative group).  Knowing the order of the group $U(p^n)$ helps a little, but in general the order of the group is not the order of every element in the group.